# can not upload image to node.js

Tags: node.js

**I am strating learning "node.js" and I have project upload image and have file upload.js but I have start upload.js, I have a error as I don't have a start upload.js**

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var multipart = require("multipart");
var sys = require("sys");
var events = require("events");
var posix = require("posix");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // Simple path-based request dispatcher
    switch (url.parse(req.url).pathname) {
        case '/':
            display_form(req, res);
            break;
        case '/upload':
            upload_file(req, res);
            break;
        default:
            show_404(req, res);
            break;
    }
});

// Server would listen on port 800
server.listen(8000);

/*
 * Display upload form
 */
function display_form(req, res) {
    res.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.sendBody(
        '<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
        '<input type="file" name="upload-file">'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
        '</form>'
    );
    res.finish();
}

/*
 * Write chunk of uploaded file
 */
function write_chunk(request, fileDescriptor, chunk, isLast, closePromise) {
    // Pause receiving request data (until current chunk is written)
    request.pause();
    // Write chunk to file
    sys.debug("Writing chunk");
    posix.write(fileDescriptor, chunk).addCallback(function() {
        sys.debug("Wrote chunk");
        // Resume receiving request data
        request.resume();
        // Close file if completed
        if (isLast) {
            sys.debug("Closing file");
            posix.close(fileDescriptor).addCallback(function() {
                sys.debug("Closed file");

                // Emit file close promise
                closePromise.emitSuccess();
            });
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Handle file upload
 */
function upload_file(req, res) {
    // Request body is binary
    req.setBodyEncoding("binary");

    // Handle request as multipart
    var stream = new multipart.Stream(req);

    // Create promise that will be used to emit event on file close
    var closePromise = new events.Promise();

    // Add handler for a request part received
    stream.addListener("part", function(part) {
        sys.debug("Received part, name = " + part.name + ", filename = " + part.filename);

        var openPromise = null;

        // Add handler for a request part body chunk received
        part.addListener("body", function(chunk) {
            // Calculate upload progress
            var progress = (stream.bytesReceived / stream.bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2);
            var mb = (stream.bytesTotal / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(1);

            sys.debug("Uploading " + mb + "mb (" + progress + "%)");

            // Ask to open/create file (if not asked before)
            if (openPromise == null) {
                sys.debug("Opening file");
                openPromise = posix.open("./uploads/" + part.filename, process.O_CREAT | process.O_WRONLY, 0600);
            }

            // Add callback to execute after file is opened
            // If file is already open it is executed immediately
            openPromise.addCallback(function(fileDescriptor) {
                // Write chunk to file
                write_chunk(req, fileDescriptor, chunk, 
                    (stream.bytesReceived == stream.bytesTotal), closePromise);
            });
        });
    });

    // Add handler for the request being completed
    stream.addListener("complete", function() {
        sys.debug("Request complete");

        // Wait until file is closed
        closePromise.addCallback(function() {
            // Render response
            res.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.sendBody("Thanks for playing!");
            res.finish();

            sys.puts("\n=> Done");
        });
    });
}

/*
 * Handles page not found error
 */
function show_404(req, res) {
    res.sendHeader(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.sendBody("You r doing it rong!");
    res.finish();
}
```

**But I have a ploblem error when start: "node upload.js: by emulator**

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'multipart'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ht/Desktop/Test/mysite/test3.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
```

Comment: req.setBodyEncoding now is req.setEncoding

Answer (score 1):

Multipart.js is a separate module now, it's not shipped with node.js anymore. You can get it [here](https://github.com/isaacs/multipart-js/).

Or you can use express to handle uploads. Check here: http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

Comment: If the answer helped you, can you please `accept` or `vote up`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're new I'd recommend you better use [express](http://expressjs.com/) to upload file. Express is built over multipart middleware. Here is a very basic example:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
fs = require('fs');
app.listen(8000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>' +
    '<input type="file" name="upload"><br>' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">' +
    '</form>'
  );
});
app.post('/upload', express.bodyParser(), function(req, res) {
  fs.rename(req.files.upload.path, path/to/your/upload/directory, function(err) {
  if(!err) res.send('uploaded!');
  });
});
```